# git: temporarily store current files - and return them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, git-stash

I know `git stash`, but somehow either I am doing something wrong or my problem is not as common as I think.

Scenario: I am coding, committed and pushed a version, doing further code, then to make a decision I would like to test something. For that, I'd love to save the current local files away and return to that state later on to try another solution. Note: in an intermediate un-committed state. Something one would do normally by zipping the project folder and restoring it later.

`git stash` for me has the crux, that I cannot tell it to simply re-apply the stashed content, ignore anything else, simply recover what was stashed. With `git stash apply --force` I get (of course) warnings that files are not committed.

Any help?

Comment: No, `git stash apply` will recover stashed content and keep stash, while `git stash pop`  will recover content and remove it from stash, queue behaviour. Both versions lead me to the same problem, telling me that I have uncommited changes ... I know, I want exactly them to be overwritten.

Comment: could you please attach screenshots of your git stash list and
what happens when you apply git stash changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git checkout` instead of `git stash apply`:

```
$ git checkout stash -- .
```

This will restore all the files in the current directory to their stashed version.

Comment: Stupid - Atom wasn't recognizing the files have changed on the disc. that works. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly you can store all untracked files with `git stash --include-untracked` (or `git stash -u` for shorten).

After you finish with the tests just revert the stash with `git stash pop`.